# Computer Crisis Takeover! [Part 1]

Tags: password, computer-puzzle

*This is part 1 of a series of multiple parts about a takeover of all the computers on earth.*

You are an elite hacker working very high up in the government; you handle many important tasks. Recently you've been called in for a very special mission, all the computers across the globe are being locked down!

The worlds top leaders unite to figure out what to do, the president of the US, the prime minister of Canada, the Russian premier, the Chinese premier, and many others. You are also invited to attend, as you are known to many as the #1 Techie on the planet.

While at the meeting you get learn new information, and take the following notes:

- Nobody can access their computers, this is slowing down large companies, small businesses, even schools.
- New computers being made are affected immediately.
- The canadian government has designed a back door program that effectively bypasses the lock and accesses a password screen.
- Nobody knows the password.
- Last but not least, the hackers cannot be traced back to.

You are tasked with the mission of unlocking a computer, finding the sinister files added, figure out who added them, and stop them.

Once you accept the mission you were given the backdoor computer, and are told that they have an emergency copy in case it breaks.

You take the computer back to your office and open it up. Once it turns on you're presented with the loading screen "Loading Glidors Ultimate..." curious enough you decide to look it up online. Then it hits you, you have no access to the Internet!

It starts up and a password screen appears, it asks you to input a password. Obviously not sure what may happen if you enter the incorrect password, you do not try to guess, instead you take out hacking tools you've developed, after attempting to run them, they come out with the error "Unknown OS". Highly disappointed, you decide to think over a tea. You go to make your tea, and when you get back you notice something weird, some pixels on the screen are different colours when you look at it differently. In fact you can clearly see that the colours are yellow, blue, red.

You take a few minutes to ponder, and then it comes to you! You type in the password and get through the lock screen!

What was the password?

**Hint:**

> It's all numbers.

**Hint2:**

> It has to do with RGB

**Final Hint:**

> RGB Values are measured as 0-1 (decimal)

Comment: In what way do you look at the screen differently?

Comment: Canada has a prime minister. Our provinces have premiers.

Comment: @JoeZ. Why don't you edit the question

Comment: How likely is someone who is able to lock down all computers in the world creating a password that can be guessed... Makes me feel this is too broad

Comment: I thought that mixing yellow, red and blue would give brown and when I googled brown, I got Emma Watson! She was in the list of notable alumni of Brown university.

Comment: ^ I will regret if the answer is not Emma Watson :) ;)

Comment: I don't know if you want to answer, but if we figure out the password, will it be obvious that it is correct?  It seems like that from the story, but the responses thus far (except for "the password") have been of a more "this might work" sort.

Comment: @Joe Z. Yes I know, I don't know how I got my own country's leader wrong XD. I just finished a book on China, so "premier" is stuck in my head. Fixed that. Surprised no one edited it.

Comment: @Rohinb97 Sorry but no... Lol. Surprised no one has got it yet.

Comment: I don't know the password, but I think the hackers are Russian. There is a painting, [Yellow-Red-Blue](http://www.wikiart.org/en/wassily-kandinsky/yellow-red-blue-1925) by Russian artist [Wassily Kandisky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassily_Kandinsky).

Comment: Or possibly Canadian because of the album [Red, Yellow, & Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red,_Yellow_%26_Blue) by Canadian band [Born Ruffians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_Ruffians).

Comment: @warspyking: Can you clarify what looking at the screen differently means? A pixel is generally a given colour. Looking at it differently doesn't make a difference unless you consider viewing angle of things like laptop screens in which case I wouldn't actually describe the pixels as being different colours... Can you clarify or is this a key part of the problem?

Comment: Technology wise, this question makes very little sense.

Comment: Trust me. You're questions are answered in later parts of the series. For now, focus on the password!

Comment: Are you sure it's yellow, blue, and red, and not Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow?

Comment: @Bach Yes. I am very sure.

Comment: @Nit The story is unrealistic, but it's not the point of the puzzle. It's just a framing device for the puzzle, "What number is related to yellow, red, and blue?" I like the story, myself =)

Comment: @Bachrach44 CMYK is generally used in print, not digitally.

Comment: @Kevin: The trouble is if the framing story makes sense how can you be sure your answer makes sense? You may be right that the question boils down to "What number is related to yellow, red and blue" but unless you know the answer for sure you can't be sure what other bits of the question are relevant and which aren't. This is why I asked whether this was relevant or not. It may be that working out this phrasing is the key of the problem.

Comment: @warspyking: I am focussing on the password but I don't know what bits of this puzzle are relevant to it or not! ;-)

Comment: It looks like a "guess what I think" riddle.  The answer is correct only because it is the one you thought about.

Comment: @FlorianF agreed - I was about to post the same thing. -1 because it apparently has no obviously-correct answer (look at all the guesses varying on RGB variations of #FF0). I'd recommend going over part 2 before posting it and really tightening up the scope of it, because as it stands it's just too open-ended for a single canonical answer (and we're led to believe there **is** a single canonical answer, else how does Elite-Hacker-Me work it out on the first guess?)

Comment: @Joe I actually assumed that my fellow puzzlers here would have solved it almost immediately. In fact someone has, but is slight incorrect as I indicated in a comment.

Comment: @warspyking slightly incorrect doesn't matter to a password screen. Cases can be made for yellow (FF0, 2552550, 255000000000255000000000000, etc), brown (630, 663300), and any variation of those. No answer feels more right that any other answer, and we'll only know an answer is right because you say that's the one you wanted to see. For example, if you said that the password field seems to be masked to only accept numerical input and limits input to a max length of 9, we have good reasons to look for a 9-digit RGB colour without any prodding

Comment: The statement that "RGB Values are measured as 0-1" is also wrong. Sometimes they are. Sometimes they are 0-255. Also sometimes you don't even use RGB but HSL, HSV, CMYK, etc. Also given the answer I'd have phrased it as "some pixels are different colours if you looks closely". But that then might beg the question of which pixels and why.  I'm personally not that big a fan still of "the major clue is only visible in certain circumstances" which is what "some pixels on the screen are different colours when you look at it differently" says to me...

Comment: OK, with the hints it is doable.  But a good puzzle should have a solution that is verifyable.  As Jason Patterson said, when you see it you know it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given everyone else's work and the 3 hints we now have, we know that we're looking for an RGB representation of yellow (as that's the only non-standard pixel colour [ie. not red, green or blue]) in the 0-1 scale format (rather than the 0-255 format).

Since the 255-scale representation is `255, 255, 0`, the 0-1 scale representation would be **`110`** (or `1 1 0`, or `1,1,0`).

---

Update: Since we're apparently not just looking for the only non-standard pixel colour, we're either looking for:

RGB notation for Yellow, Red, Blue: **110001100**
or
RGB notation for mixing Yellow, Red, Blue: **492449** (assuming 00-99 to avoid decimals)

Comment: No, there's a reason I included the other 2 colours.

Comment: Use @warspyking to notify me if you edit.

Comment: Take a look at Kevin's answer. What if you put that in the same form as your own?

Comment: @warspyking updated

Comment: Finally! I thought you guys would solve this so much faster than that.

Comment: @warspyking: So which of the two given answers was actually right in the end?

Comment: @Chris I'd imagine that 110001100 is correct. It's not based on as much guesswork (ie. would 00-99 be 000-999, etc)

Comment: @Chris Sorry never noticed that comment for the longest time... The first.

Answer (score 6):

Look at Nick R's answer.

> "This is on the right track, but wrong noneoftheless" - OP (warspyking)

Brown because when you mix yellow, red and blue you get brown.
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120328201707AAZNGvj

Edit in response to "it's all numbers":

Nobody has a answer yet so I will continue with my logic - could be hex code, which the "#1 Techie on the Planet" would definitely know about. Is it a mere coincidence that the hex code for brown (663300) has no letters in it despite the fact that it is shown in a base 16?

> *The password is 663300.*

Also - meta-puzzling:(if this is frowned upon please tell me - I am new to puzzling SE)
The OP is a programmer (as is shown by multiple tech related SE accounts including Stack Overflow)
1 of the 7 questions he asks is on SO about contains a single line of  JavaScript and a **hex color code**. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584703/cannot-change-the-colour-of-html-element-with-javascript
This solution seems likely to me.

Comment: Nope. This is not I'm the right track. Emi987 is closest atm.

Comment: Also yes, I am a programmer, but usually it's in Lua. That question was when I was making a chrome extension, and had a noob problem!

Comment: I figured that the odds of having any random hex code be all numbers was: (abcdef) 9/15 - roll 6 15 sided dice and if they are all 1-9 then this is a accident (: I should have known lua typically uses RGB values...

Answer (score 3):

If the pw is only numbers and looking at the Nick R answer..

> .. the password is the values of a color on the screen in RGB. According to the text, yellow is the only one different from the classic green-red-blue, so I could suppose the password is **2552550**

**EDIT:**

Maybe the password is too easy right now. Adding some numbers..

> .. the result could be **255000000255255000000000255**, the values of the R[ed]-Y[ellow]-B[lue] pixels of the screen.

Not sure about that one, it's riddling me "Unknows OS", but maybe it's just a sensation.

Comment: Wow we're getting close!

Answer (score 2):

> Only Columbia has a flag that is yellow-blue-red in that order.
>  So the password is "columbia".
>  
>  There is also Equador.  But with coat of arms. Try that also.

Comment: You're way off. But this answer does fit the bill, but it's not the password.

Comment: By fit the bill I mean it corresponds with the hints. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In the additive colour model (which is what to expect from pixels), the colours Red + Blue + Yellow combine to form the colour White.  You initially just saw this white light, before you looked at it more carefully or differently and saw the underlying pixels of red, blue and yellow.

You decide to try the password of the colour white in RGB notation, which is given by:

255255255

Or alternatively, depending on your colour mixing algorithim could yield (170,085,085) and therefore the password could be:

170085085

Answer (score 2):

If the clue is the yellow pixel, then the solution must be the computer representation of yellow. Since we know 31337 hackers would never pick a short password, it must be as long as possible, hence:

> 255255000

or

> if they're using the CMYK scheme: 000255000

Comment: We're getting very close here...

Comment: @warspyking Mix all 3 and get 255255255?

Comment: Nope. You're on the right track.

Comment: @warspyking last guess - FFFF00 + 0000FF + FF0000 - the FF+FF in the red value caused a buffer overflow (hacker math), yielding 00FFFF, or a password of 000255255

Comment: No sorry that's not it either.

Answer (score 1):

The password was "the password", because in the last line you said he types in "the password" and got through the lock screen!

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why my solution is not a possible one?

Comment: The answer is too facetious and smart-alecky. (For the record, I didn't downvote you.)

Comment: Somebody had to say it.

Comment: Why is humor often penalized here? Even though humorous, this answer is legit. If you don't like it just don't upvote it.

Comment: I actually just downvoted this because if it were the password, it would have quotes around it in the question: "You type in 'the password'"

Comment: @warspyking, not necessarily because I have seen similar puzzles where the quotations marks have been omitted.

Comment: West Gate of Moria, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of ideas about this, but from my reading of the puzzle the answer should be obvious rather than an "I think this could be it" kind of response.  That said, here is my response.  I think this could be it.

> The password is "primary".  The three pixels are the primary colors and this is also the first (primary) puzzle in the series and likely the first challenge that will have to be overcome by the hacker.

Comment: Smart but not quite.

Answer (score 1):

What if we concatenate the decimal representations of all three colors, in the order they appear on the screen?

- Yellow is 2552550
- Blue is 00255
- Red is 25500

If each of the RBG values needs to be three digits long, the values are 255255000, 000000255, and 255000000.

So my guess is either `25525500025525500` or `255255000000000255255000000`.

Comment: Nice answer, but how do you determine whether to put yellow first, blue first or red first in your password?

Comment: This is correct BUT it has 1 thing wrong with it.

Comment: @Mew The specific order in the question is, "In fact you can clearly see that the colours are yellow, blue, red."

Answer (score 1):

Colors: {yellow, blue, red} (note all following are numbers)

Making assumption that password should be easy to remember and hard to crack with [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) most likely password would would be :

> **FFFF000000FFFF0000** (hackers would see **F** as a number).

On off chance i would want to pick a password with only numbers it would be :

> **101010100101010101010101**

Reasoning behind my decision would be **guess = what it is (cracking time with average pc)**:

- 111111111111111100000000000000000000000011111111111111110000000000000000 =  concatenate 24-bit RGB values as binary value (7 septendecillion years)
- FFFF000000FFFF0000 = concatenate 24-bit RGB values as hexadecimal value (81 billion years)
- 255255000000000255255000000 = concatenate 24-bit RGB values  (7 billion years)
- 1111111101111111111111111 = sum of 24-bit RGB values as binary value (79 million years)
- 101010100101010101010101 = avarage 24-bit RGB values as binary value (7 million years)
- 4722294425279902187520 = concatenate 24-bit RGB values as base 10 number (79 thousand years)
- 570590450475625750 = concatenate start and end of color wavelength (7 years)
- 25525500025525500 = concatenate 24-bit RGB values (289 days)
- 1111111111111111 = bitwise and 24-bit RGB values as binary value (28 days)
- 5702045025625125 = concatenate start and diapason of color wavelength (28 days)
- 1feffff = sum of 24-bit RGB values as hexadecimal value (19 seconds)
- 00FFFF = bitwise and 24-bit RGB values as hexadecimal value (0.544195584 seconds)
- AA5555 = avarage 24-bit RGB values as hexadecimal value (0.544195584 seconds)
- 33488895 = sum of 24-bit RGB values (0.025 seconds)
- 0255255 = bitwise and 24-bit RGB values (0.0025 seconds)
- 1708585 = avarage 24-bit RGB values (0.0025 seconds)
- 602400 = concatenate hue HSV/HSL (0.00025 seconds)