# Computer Crisis Takeover! [Part 2!]

Tags: password

**My last part 2 was sort of not a puzzle (oops) I've made sure this fits the criteria!**

*This is part 2 of a series of multiple parts about a takeover of all the computers on earth. The links to previous questions are here:*

[Computer Crisis Takeover! [Part 1]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3853/computer-crisis-takeover-part-1)

After cracking the original password screen, you open up this new OS "Glidors Ultimate". You are welcomed and all of a sudden a message pops up saying you've been locked out for not being the owner of this OS.

It gives you a second chance to get in by allowing you to guess the backup password. You only get 1 try, and there's a password hint included on the screen! Perhaps this hacker thought he'd need it to jog his memory if he ever needed to use this screen?

The password hint is as follows;

> I'm Not the neWest, but I'm also nOt olD, I am but in betWeen. ^

What is this password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a stretch...

> windows vista

because

> There are actually 5 capitalized letters: N,W,O,D,W, and I (the last I in '...I am...'). together they make the word WINDOW - the '^' symbol  is created by hitting shift+6, the 6th edition of windows is vista, ergo 'windows vista'

Comment: Not quite.... On the right track with capital letters though.

Comment: @warspyking updated my answer

Comment: Except he's already said it isn't shifted.

Comment: @warspyking Sorry I missed that anecdote-I came up with a much more reasonable answer this time :)

Comment: @schil227 So very close... You just need to fix what ^ means.

Comment: @warspyking I got you figured out now!

Comment: technically, vista is not the 6th "edition" (Microsoft has a big problem creating numbers that make sense; witness the jump from 8 to 10), rather it is NT kernel version 6.0.  Since Windows 7 and 8 are (strangely) NT kernel versions 6.1 and 6.2, Vista isn't technically the only "6".  However, it did coincide with being one less than consumer "version" 7, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

The password is:

> WINDOW6

(Sorry, I can't get the formatting to work with spoiler tags.)

Here's why:

Rewriting the riddle on separate lines we get:

> I'm Not the neWest
>
> but I'm also nOt olD
>
> I am but in betWeen. ^

Next we extract the capitalized letters:

> I N W
>
> I O D
>
> I W

So,

> rearrange the letters to get WINDOW and shift+6 is caret.

Comment: Very close, but that's not what ^ means. But on the right track looking at the capitalized letters.

Comment: @warspyking edited to use a different interpretation of the caret.

Comment: Still not it. I get the feeling you've almost found it though.

Comment: @warspyking Maybe you're right. I don't feel that way at all.

Comment: @warspyking ok, how about that?

Comment: Well now I feel like you're just guessing... There's an I, N, W, O, D and W.

Comment: @warspyking Yeah I wasn't sure if I should count the capitals that were already capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

I think the password is

> WINDOWS XP

From

> I'm Not the neWest
>
> but I'm also nOt olD
>
> I am but in betWeen.

Taking the upper-case letters and arranging, we get

> WINDOW

^ is used

> to denote power, exponent. so I guess ^ = "eXponent"

When making it short

> ^ = XP

Then we will get

> WINDOW XP

Now take the hints again.

> I'm Not the neWest
>
> but I'm also nOt olD
>
> I am but in betWeen.

Which made me to think that the password must be

> WINDOWS XP

Since

> Windows XP is not the newest. (WINDOWS 10 is the newest)
> Windows XP is not OLD too. There are many people who are still using Windows XP. Windows 98, 2000 etc are old.
> Windows XP is in between.

Comment: I would count CP as old... Just think about ^. What exact is ^. How do you make ^?

Comment: Got the idea now. Will update my answer.

Comment: I would count XP as old I mean*

Comment: Can I ask for a clue? Is the password a word/words(meaningful)

Comment: Yes it is. It isn't jibberish like gddhjf ugh  d{%^|€=?,!~{\?+}*>}.7.D/<,z,5>| lol

Comment: Then I ended up in a wrong way. What I got was "COTJUC". Let me think further and will get back to you with the solution once I figure it out.

Comment: You're really close, you're just off with the ^ part.