# Computer Crisis Takeover! [Part 3]

Tags: computer-puzzle, mystery

*This is part 3 of a series of multiple parts about a takeover of all the computers on earth. The links to previous questions are here:*

- [Computer Crisis Takeover! [Part 1]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3853/computer-crisis-takeover-part-1)
- [Computer Crisis Takeover! [Part 2!]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5431/computer-crisis-takeover-part-2)

You just cracked another password screen due to being the invalid owner of the OS. Now that you're in you start looking through numerous file paths finding nothing but folders and folders of nothing. Then it hits you that they could be hidden. Noticing that the OS is unbelievably like Windows you enable hidden folders and system folders in the options. Suddenly it reopens the process and you're in a folder with 5 executables:

> B.exe
>   A.exe
>   I.exe
>   BE.exe
>   AF.exe

There's also a text file called *Instructions.txt*. Before even daring to do anything, you open the instructions. The contents are as shown:

> Dear User,
>
> I have made a little game to pass the time! There's 5 executables in a folder, the order in which you execute them will decide on the result! Access to system files will be granted if correct. OS Shut down will result if wrong!
>
> Here's the hint you'll need to figure it out. *Let letters be known as the master of words, let words be known as the peasants to numbers, let numbers be known as kings to words*.
>
> Good luck, Dr. Glin!

What order should you open these executables in?

Comment: Is Bexe supposed to be B.exe?

Comment: @Ric Yes it is sorry.

Comment: Is it intentional that you write "let word" not let "words"? I am thinking on a specific "word" as in number type word then...

Comment: Any reason why the contents of the hidden folder are not in natural alphabetic order?

Answer (score 1):

> BE.exe, B.exe, A.exe, I.exe, AF.exe

Reasoning:

> The order is numbers>letters>words. Letters A-e can be interpreted as numbers via hexadecimal. So the three titles which can be hex are A,B, and BE, whose values are 10, 11, and 176 (ordered greatest to least for answer) the remaining two are a letter "I" and a word "AF". Since letters are greater than words, "I" is executed before "AF".

Comment: Umm no, sorry. But wrong.

Comment: AF can also be interpreted as Hexadecimal as 175. BE is 190 in decimal as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> I.exe, AF.exe, B.exe, A.exe, BE.exe

Because:

> Assuming the order should be numbers, letters, words based on kings > masters > peasants: 
>
>  1. I.exe because it can be a number (roman numeral 1);
>  2. AF.exe and B.exe
>     because they can be neither numbers nor words, and just going in
>     alphabetical order;
>  3. A.exe and BE.exe because they are words, and also
>     sorted alphabetically